# Problems with Directory API: Custom User Schema

Tags: google-apps-script, google-directory-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm programming a function in order to update users' info. I did it and it works fine however it doesn't work when I want to use custom schemas. I checked the [reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-schemas#set_fields) but it showed an error **"Invalid Input: [employmentData] "**

```
function directoryUpdate(userId, userDept, userLocation, userPhone,userTitle) {

var userId = 'devtest@pruebatest.com',userDept='D003', userLocation='L003';
var userTitle='T003';

var update = {

ims: 
[{
type: "work",
protocol: "gtalk",
im: "liz_im@talk.example.com",
primary: true
}],
emails: [
 {
 address: "liz@example.com",
 type: "home",
 customType: "",
 primary: true
 }
 ],


addresses: 
  [{
     type: "home",
     customType: "",
     streetAddress: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
     locality: "Mountain View",
     region: "CA",
     postalCode: "94043" 
 }
  ],
organizations: 
  [{
    name: "Next Step",
    title: userTitle,
    primary: true,
    type: "work",
    department: userDept,
    location: userLocation
  }],

  customSchemas: {
  employmentData: {
   employeeNumber: "123456789",
   jobFamily: "Engineering",
   location: "Atlanta",
   jobLevel: 8,
   projects: [
    { value: "GeneGnome", customType: "development" },
    { value: "Panopticon", customType: "support" }
   ]
  }
 }

};
update = AdminDirectory.Users.patch(update, userId);
Logger.log('User %s updated with result %s.', userId, update)
return true;
}
```

What's the error?

Greetings, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried the same with basic fields such as name, id etc... and it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

The employmentData field is inside the "customSchemas" field. Custom schemas have to be defined before using them. 
To create a Custom Schema you have to use the resource [Schemas.insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/schemas/insert).

After creating the schema with the correspondent fields and type of value (STRING, INT, ETC) your code should run without issues. I tried it and worked for me.

Also, after updating the user, when making the call to Users.get, you have to set the parameter "projection=full" in order to see these values in the response.